# eBay App-like Loading Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ebay-api

I'm making an iPhone app that primarily focuses on loading webpages in UIWebviews.  To show the user that the web page is currently loading, I'd like the screen to display a loading animation while the page loads, similar to the eBay app:

[image: eBay app loading animation]

**How can I do this?**  **Or, at least, what UIWebView methods could I use to tell me if the page is loading and that there is internet connection (so it's not blindly trying to load forever).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD), a open source component which will do a lot of the work for you.

You'll need to create a delegate of the UIWebView and respond to the didStartLoading and didFinishLoading messages (that's when you'll show an hide the progress view).

Comment: Will didStartLoading be triggered if there is no internet?

Comment: Try it and see: you can enable Airplane Mode on a device or just unplug your computer from the Internet on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is just having it there until you need it and setting the alpha from 0 to 1.

You would just need a gray thing (or whatever that **thing** is) and a activity indicator.

You could also dig into the alerts section in apple but I think the above is easier.

Comment: Would having it on all of the time, just hidden, take up unneeded processing?